# Separate JS and CSS list output of media class object for Django form in template

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I have simple question here. I know how to use django media in order to put js and css files which is specified in media class like this:

**In forms.py for model**

```
from django import forms

class CalendarWidget(forms.TextInput):
    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('pretty.css',)
        }
        js = ('animations.js', 'actions.js')
```

**In template file**

```
{{ form.media }}
```

However I want to put separately JS and CSS. It means I want to put CSS at head section and JS before body tag. So how I can achieve it using build in tags? Is it possible?

**P.S.** I cannot find out information from django documentation. (Perhaps, I look in wrong place). So give me a hint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `{{form.media.css}}` and `{{form.media.js}}` separately to put them at required places.

Reference docs [subsets-of-assets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/media/#subsets-of-assets).